# Having an array out of bounds exception. How do i fix this?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, exception

I am trying to write a Java program that reads in a data file and reads the integers into a standard integer array (not an ArrayList), sorts the array, and displays the values from lowest to highest. I also need to write a sort function that uses bubble sort or selection sort to do the sorting. I keep getting this error: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8" in lines 39 and 52. How do I fix this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Declaring variables
    String name;

    // Declaring scanner for name of file
    Scanner iscanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Reading in file name
    System.out.println("What is the name of your file?" );
    name = iscanner.next();

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(name);

    // Declaring scanner for inside the file
    Scanner inp;

    try {

        // Assigning scanner to the file
        inp = new Scanner(file);

        // Declaring array
        int [] nums = new int [(int) name.length()];

        // Reading integers into array
        for (int i =0; i < name.length(); i++)
        {
            nums[i] = inp.nextInt();
        }
        // THIS IS LINE 39*****************
        // Calling sorting function
        bubblesort(nums);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void bubblesort(int[] nums){
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    { // THIS IS LINE 52**************************
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
        {
            if(nums[i] > nums[j+1])
            {
                temp = nums[j+1];
                nums[j+1] = nums[i];
                nums[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(nums[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: name.length() - 1

Comment: I'm like 99% you have line 52 marked wrong, but the line `if(nums[i] > nums[j+1])` makes no checks that `nums[j+1]` is valid

Comment: what is the relation between `name.length()`  (filename) and the size of `nums` ?

Comment: Did you really mean for the number of slots in your array to be the same as the number of characters in your filename?  This seems to me to be a very odd way to choose the size an array.

Comment: What debugging techniques have you tried?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an array out of bounds exception due to your use of `j + 1`. Your inner loop counts up to `nums.length - 1`, which you then add one to. Thus, you're accessing the array at `nums.length`, which causes the exception. To fix this, adjust your bounds on the array, such as stopping at `j < nums.length - 1`.